# Display message twice on the page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, messages, success-message, error-message

I'd like to display the default Magento page message block twice on the Cart page.

It is now displayed at the top of the page. I would also like to display it at the bottom. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you try anything for this one?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below code in your checkout layout XML file. i.e. `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        ...
    </referenceContainer>
    ...
    <referenceContainer name="page.messages.bottom">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages.bottom" as="messages"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

****====UPDATE====****

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

The above layout update will make use of Magento's message default template to display the messages.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: @zekia, I have updated my answer please check it.

Comment: I'm still getting page messages once in page